# dynamic query with Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I want to build an Shiny application which is connected to a database, my problem  is how to create the query dynamically, here i put an example where the user have four research axis(you need just to copy the code in your R enviroment), but in my application i have 12 research axis and i don't know how manage the query, if you have an idea ?

```
# rm(list=ls())
library(sqldf)
library(car)
data(Moore)
ContextElements = colnames(Moore)
ContextElements[1] = 'partner_status'
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel(h3("Data Select", style="background-color:gray")),
hr(),
div(class="row-fluid", style="height=350px; background-color:lightgray",
    column(width=3,
           uiOutput("firstAxe"),
           uiOutput("firstAxeOutput")
    ),
    column(width=3,
           uiOutput("secondAxe"),
           uiOutput('type1'),
           uiOutput("secondAxeOutput")
    ),
    column(width=3,
           uiOutput("thirdAxe"),
           uiOutput('type2'),
           uiOutput("thirdAxeOutput")
    ),
    column(width=3,
           uiOutput("fourthAxe"),
           uiOutput('type3'),
           uiOutput("fourthAxeOutput")
    )
),
hr(),
hr(),
div(class="row-fluid",
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("mainQuery"))),
hr(),
div(class="row-fluid",
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("query1"))),
div(class="row-fluid",
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("query2"))),
div(class="row-fluid",
    column(12,
           verbatimTextOutput("query3")))

)),
server=function(input, output){
buildQuery= reactive({

})
output$mainQuery = renderPrint(buildQuery())
###############
### first Axis
output$firstAxe= renderUI({
  selectInput(inputId = "firstAxe", label = h4("First Axis"), 
              choices=c(Choose='',ContextElements), multiple = FALSE) 
})    
# output Query
output$firstAxeOutput=renderUI({
  if(!is.null(input$firstAxe)){
    if(input$firstAxe==""){
      selectInput(inputId = "firstAxeOutput", label="", choices = NULL,   multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
    }else{
      query = paste('select distinct ', input$firstAxe, ' from Moore order by ', input$firstAxe, sep='')
      choicesValues = sqldf(query)
      selectInput(inputId = "firstAxeOutput", label="", choices = choicesValues[[1]], multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
    } 
  }          
})
###############
### second Axis
precAxeRes1 =reactive(paste(input$firstAxeOutput, collapse = "','"))
output$type1 = renderPrint(precAxeRes1())
output$secondAxe= renderUI({
  firstSel = input$firstAxe
  ContextElements = setdiff(ContextElements, firstSel)
  selectInput(inputId = "secondAxe", label = h4("Second Axis"), 
              choices=c(Choose='',ContextElements), multiple = FALSE) 
})
# output Query
output$secondAxeOutput=renderUI({      
  if(!is.null(input$secondAxe)){
    if(input$secondAxe=="" || input$firstAxe==""){
      selectInput(inputId = "secondAxeOutput", label="", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
    }else{
      if(is.null(input$firstAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$secondAxe, ' from Moore  where ',
                      input$firstAxe, " like ('%') order by ",   input$secondAxe , sep='')
        #             query = paste('select distinct ', input$secondAxe, ' from Moore order by ', input$secondAxe, sep='')  
      }else{
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$secondAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes1(), "') order by ", input$secondAxe , sep='') 
      }          
      choicesValues = sqldf(query)
      output$query1 = renderPrint(paste("Second Query: ",query))
      selectInput(inputId = "secondAxeOutput", label="", choices = choicesValues[[1]], multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
    } 
  } 
})
###############
### third Axis
precAxeRes2 =reactive(paste(input$secondAxeOutput, collapse = "','"))
output$type2 = renderPrint(precAxeRes2())
output$thirdAxe= renderUI({
  precSel = c(input$firstAxe, input$secondAxe)
  ContextElements = setdiff(ContextElements, precSel)
  selectInput(inputId = "thirdAxe", label = h4("Third Axis"), 
              choices=c(Choose='',ContextElements), multiple = FALSE) 
})
# output Query
output$thirdAxeOutput=renderUI({
  if(!is.null(input$thirdAxe)){
    if(input$thirdAxe=="" || input$secondAxe==""){
      selectInput(inputId = "thirdAxeOutput", label="", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
    }else{
      if(is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && is.null(input$secondAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$thirdAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " like ('%') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " like ('%') order by " , input$thirdAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else if(!is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && is.null(input$secondAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$thirdAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " in ('",precAxeRes1(), "') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " like ('%') order by " , input$thirdAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else if(is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && !is.null(input$secondAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$thirdAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " like ('%') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes2(), "') order by " , input$thirdAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else{
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$thirdAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " in ('",precAxeRes1(), "') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes2(), "') order by " , input$thirdAxe,
                      sep='')
      }         
      choicesValues = sqldf(query)
      output$query2 = renderPrint(paste("Third Query: ",query))
      selectInput(inputId = "thirdAxeOutput", label="", choices = choicesValues[[1]], multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
    } 
  } 
})
###############
### fourth Axis
precAxeRes3 =reactive(paste(input$thirdAxeOutput, collapse = "','"))
output$type3 = renderPrint(precAxeRes3())
output$fourthAxe= renderUI({
  precSel = c(input$firstAxe, input$secondAxe, input$thirdAxe)
  ContextElements = setdiff(ContextElements, precSel)
  selectInput(inputId = "fourthAxe", label = h4("Fourth Axis"), 
              choices=c(Choose='',ContextElements), multiple = FALSE) 
})
# output Query
output$fourthAxeOutput=renderUI({
  if(!is.null(input$fourthAxe)){
    if(input$fourthAxe=="" || input$thirdAxe==""){
      selectInput(inputId = "fourthAxeOutput", label="", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
    }else{ 

      if(is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && is.null(input$secondAxeOutput) && is.null(input$thirdAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$fourthAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " like ('%') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " like ('%') and ",
                      input$thirdAxe, " like ('%') order by " , input$fourthAxe,
                      sep='')
        #             query = paste('select distinct ', input$thirdAxe, ' from Moore order by ',  input$thirdAxe, sep='')
      }else if(!is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && !is.null(input$secondAxeOutput) && is.null(input$thirdAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$fourthAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " in ('",precAxeRes1(), "') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes2(), "') and ",
                      input$thirdAxe, " like ('%') order by " , input$fourthAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else if(!is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && is.null(input$secondAxeOutput) && !is.null(input$thirdAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$fourthAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " in ('",precAxeRes1(), "') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " like ('%') and ",
                      input$thirdAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes3(), "') order by " , input$fourthAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else if(!is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && is.null(input$secondAxeOutput) && is.null(input$thirdAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$fourthAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " in ('",precAxeRes1(), "') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " like ('%') and ",
                      input$thirdAxe, " like ('%') order by " , input$fourthAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else if(is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && !is.null(input$secondAxeOutput) && !is.null(input$thirdAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$fourthAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " like ('%') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes2(), "') and ",
                      input$thirdAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes3(), "') order by " , input$fourthAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else if(is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && !is.null(input$secondAxeOutput) && is.null(input$thirdAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$fourthAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " like ('%') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes2(), "') and ",
                      input$thirdAxe, " like ('%') order by " , input$fourthAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else if(!is.null(input$firstAxeOutput) && !is.null(input$secondAxeOutput) && !is.null(input$thirdAxeOutput)){
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$fourthAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " in ('",precAxeRes1(), "') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes2(), "') and ",
                      input$thirdAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes3(), "') order by " , input$fourthAxe,
                      sep='')
      }else{
        query = paste('select distinct ', input$fourthAxe, ' from Moore where ',
                      input$firstAxe,  " like ('%') and ",
                      input$secondAxe, " like ('%') and ",
                      input$thirdAxe, " in ('",precAxeRes3(), "') order by " , input$fourthAxe,
                      sep='')            
      } 
      choicesValues = sqldf(query)
      output$query3 = renderPrint(paste("Fourth Query: ",query))
      selectInput(inputId = "fourthAxeOutput", label="", choices =  choicesValues[[1]], multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE) 
    }
  }
})
}
)
)
```

regards

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking.  Are you just looking how to simplify your code or is there a specific error you are troubleshooting?

Comment: i am asking to simplify my code, because in my real application i have 12  research axis, in the case of my example, i can test all the possibilities, because i have just 4 axis. as you can see i repeat the query every time in my code, i want to create a global query and every time the user choose one axis ==> global query + the new axis choice

Comment: Please do not post code that might damage the reader's workspace.

Comment: @ G.Grothendieck, where is the damage with my code? it's just an example, you need R and (Shiny and  sqldf) packages

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a dynamic query from a reactive shiny widget. I hope this helps someone :

https://github.com/victor-geere/R